# php5 google checkout simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

I want ot get response for the google checkout .I have used 
http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP_CheckoutShoppingCartDemo.html#googleCheckoutFunctionDisplayDiagnoseResponse

The code uses the dom_xml method which php5 does not support.
How i can use simpleXMl or DomDocument
Please help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use the dom_xml?  The website shows that you can use curl to acheive this function.  Which is recommended.  Here is the blurb from their website. Sorry in advance if you don't have a way to use curl.

> ```
> Requirements:
> 1. PHP4 or PHP5 with cURL(libcurl) installed and enabled.
>   *Domxml(libxml) is NOT required.
> 2. SSL certificate installed on your server for level 2 integration.
> ```

Website with Above Text: http://code.google.com/p/google-checkout-php-sample-code/

---

> Info on Curl Request via Google
>   Checkout API:
>   http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/samples/Google_Checkout_Sample_Code_PHP_GlobalAPIFunctions.html#googleCheckoutFunctionGetCurlResponse
>
> PHP Info for Curl: 
>   php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

---

If you can't use curl, you can mod the api if needed.  You can always open a issues ticket from the above link.

Hope this helps...